# Dual image map restricts to open sets?

Tags: general-topology, continuity, category-theory, adjoint-functors

A book I'm reading on category theory says that if $A$ and $B$ are topological spaces and $f:A\to B$ is continuous, then the "dual image" map
$$f_*(U)=\{\,b\in B\mid f^{-1}(b)\subseteq U\,\}$$
restricts to open sets; that is, $f_*:\mathcal{O}(A)\to\mathcal{O}(B)$. (So then it's right adjoint to $f^{-1}:\mathcal{O}(B)\to\mathcal{O}(A)$.)

This seems wrong, since it would imply for example (taking $U=\varnothing$) that the image of a continuous function is always closed.

Are there natural conditions under which it does make sense to restrict to open sets?

Comment: It's definitely the case if $f$ is a homeomorphism because then $f_*(U)=f(U) $, whence $f^{-1}(f_*(U))=U$ making $f_*(U)$ open whenever $U$ is open. One could potentially weaker the condition by requiring $f$ to be such that $f_*(U) = f(U)$ and $f^{-1}(f(U)) \subseteq U$ for any open $U$.

Comment: The correct version of the claim is that $f^{-1} : \mathcal{O} (B) \to \mathcal{O} (A)$ has a right adjoint. It is defined by $f_* U = \{ b \in B : \exists V \in \mathcal{O} (B) . b \in V \text{ and } f^{-1} V \subseteq U \}$.

Comment: @ZhenLin Thanks, that works. Do you know offhand any sources using that definition? I didn't find any when searching on "dual image" earlier.

Comment: I don't remember. It's an easy calculation, anyway. You might find it written as $f_* U = \bigcup \{ V \in \mathcal{O} (B) : f^{-1} V \subseteq U \}$ instead.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You’re right that there’s a problem here.

Let $A=(0,1)\times(0,1)$ and $B=(0,1)$, each with the usual topology, and let $$f:A\to B:\langle x,y\rangle\mapsto x$$ be the projection to the $x$-axis; this is a continuous, open map. Let $$U=\{\langle x,y\rangle\in A:y>2x-1\}\;.$$ $U$ is open in $A$, but

$$f_*(U)=\left(0,\frac12\right]\;,$$

which is not open in $B$.

You do get the result if $f$ is closed and continuous. In that case let $U$ be open in $A$, and let $F=A\setminus U$. Suppose that $b\in B$; then $f^{-1}[\{b\}]\subseteq U$ iff $b\notin f[F]$, i.e., iff $b\in B\setminus f[F]$, so $f_*(U)=B\setminus f[F]$, which is open in $B$.

Comment: I like that you use $[ \_ ]$ for direct and inverse image. I'd always thought that using $( \_ )$ leads to lots of confusion, especially for beginners. Same for $\langle \_, \_ \rangle$ for ordered pairs.

Comment: @LeoSera: Yes, plain parentheses really do get overloaded.